# Error al cargar PDF con CodeIgniter DOMPDF

Tags: php, html, codeigniter

estoy exportando un archivo PDF con la librería DomPDF en CodeIgniter, pero me esta dando este error al cargar:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Por el momento, este el código con el que estoy trabajando:

Controlador:

```
public function pdf(){
    $this->load->library('pdf');
    $html = $this->load->view('pdf.html');
    $this->pdf->load_html(preg_replace('/>\s+</', '><', $html));
    $this->pdf->render();
    $this->pdf->stream("reporte.pdf", array("Attachment" => 0));
}
```

Este el archivo donde cargo la librería:

```
require_once 'dompdf/autoload.inc.php';
use Dompdf\Dompdf;
class Pdf extends Dompdf{
function __construct(){
    parent:: __construct();
    $pdf = new Dompdf();
  }
}
```

Y mi vista:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>

<h1>Prueba desde PDF</h1>

</body>
</html>
```

No sé a que se debería este problema.

Comment: probá dándole una ruta completa en `$html = $this->load->view('pdf.html');` puede que no encuentre el archivo

Comment: Ya lo probé pero siempre me da el mismo problema

Comment: ¿Qué versión de DomPDF estás usando?

Comment: @A.Cedano La versión 0.8.6

Comment: ¿Podrías probar primero con algo simple, como el ejemplo que ponen ellos [en la sección **Quick Start**](https://github.com/dompdf/dompdf#quick-start)?